# Css-animation: changing images in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make animation similar to this https://cardsagainsthumanity.com/ right top corner on the page. Though it's tough to exactly do like this (if you know exactly how to do this, please let me know) but i have decided to make a simplified version of this.
I have made black & white cards along-with zoomIn effect in css design with the below code (Press Run code snippet at bottom to see how it looks like).

Now, there are two problems:
1. To replace these three cards (first combination) with next three cards (second combination #they're not in the code#), so on and run these different combinations in a bigger infinite loop. [High priority]
2. To display the cards one by one. Ex- first the black card should come, followed by the first white card, second white card and so on. Currently, our all cards appear together on screen at once. [Low priority].

Now, I tried solving the first problem in CSS after reading different answers on the forum, but it didn't work. I don't know if we can solve it through Javascript or jquery, as I'm not much familiar with them.
It will be a great help if you can help me to solve atleast first problem.

```css
.blackcard {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 54px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.stage {
  background: #232323;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.whitecard {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 54px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="css/cards.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="whitecard zoomIn">
      <p2>Sleeping.</p2>
    </div>
    <div class="whitecard zoomIn">
      <p>Coding.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blackcard zoomIn">
      <p> What are you doing?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i were doing this, I would go straight to Javascript.

You could use an array with lots of different values for the white cards and have the value update 'randomly' on the white card.

So for example your array could be

```
var exampleArray = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
```

Then using javascript you could alter the div.whitecard p value using an array value....looping over.

Honestly, don't have the time to write out an example, the jist of this would be to use Javascript and treat it as your friend!!!!!

See edit based on your comments below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myGreetingSkills"></div>

<script>
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var skills = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"],
      counter = skills.length - 1,
      previousSkill = $("#myGreetingSkills"),
      arraylength = skills.length - 1;

    function display_skills() {
      if (counter === arraylength) {
          counter = 0;
      }
      else {
          counter++;  
      }
      previousSkill.html(skills[counter]);
    }

    display_skills();

    setInterval(function() {
      display_skills();
    }, 2000);
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It gives me a direction to head towards JavaScript. I got a feeling what you want to say.

Comment: No worries, I learnt the basic foundation of javascript years ago now from The New Boston, the first video in the tutorial is here; 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQaAGmHNn9s&list=PL46F0A159EC02DF82

The latest javascript techniques are not used here, but the basic foundations still are relevant

Comment: Hey Alex, I found the exact code what I was looking for on js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6uytz209/  but it's not working on my dreamweaver. I mean where to exactly place this code and how to upload jQuery in html.

Comment: Perfect, so a similar solution to what I mentioned, you need to have a basic HTML page, then you need to get jquery referenced in <head> section on your page.  You could then, at the bottom, before the ending </body> tag put the code from this fiddle inbetween two script tags...

`code`